# how to manually enable debug mode on galaxy s4 with black screen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, usb-debugging

Trying to enable the debug mode on galaxy s4 in order to share the screen to PC via vysor since the phone has black screen totally. The screen responds to touch even though it's totally black. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment this but i don't have enough rep yet.
Off the top of my head i'd say your best hope is to [watch a youtube video of someone doing it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFg0tJ52Hhs) and try to replicate the touches, for a sense of if your hitting something you can turn vibrate on (using the volume controls). Other than that you could always claim warranty or try to get a new screen. 
Hope i helped

Comment: thanks for your reply. i tried following a video to do it but seems i always fail to get something right so wasn't successful. i guess there's no other solution but to fix the screen considering my situation.

Comment: @Rockix Sorry to hear it, good luck with the screen though!